# @nivo/line: How to keep the last point active on mouse leave?

Tags: reactjs, nivo-slider

This is the state of the graph on mouse hover:

[image: line chart]

When the mouse leaves, the tooltip and crosshairs disappear:

[image: line chart]

I want to always keep the tooltip and the crosshairs of the last active point even if the cursor is out of focus of the chart. It is possible?